# Python: scipy.optimize.minimize vs Nested Loops

Tags: python

Just a curious question.

[image]

Let's imagine I have a function testFunc(a,b,c). I need to find a value(-s) of "a,b,c" where the function is minimum with 100% accuracy. Bounds of "a,b,c" are limited. Calculation time is not critical (it could work for a long time).

Which way is better in this case: try to find and optimize some method in "scipy.optimize.minimize" or just write several Nested Loops to go over each value of (a,b,c) and just take minimum value of the function?

**EDIT:**

Would you use Nested Loops or "scipy.optimize.minimize" in a such case?

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "better".

Comment: Yeah, we could dig into details like costs / accuracy and so on. Added my general question to the topic.

Comment: Then it's too broad question. The exact solution can only be found if there're just finite number of values that your variables may take. `scipy.optimize.minimize` assumes that variables are continuos. So, if you use discrete scale for your variables there're methods like `itertools.product` which emulates nested loops for you. You should make your question more specific, so that it could be answered without conversations.